# Chat window with css

Tags: html, css, chat

I am stuck with a chat window which we create with the help of CSS after, before elements. My code is added below.
My questions are:

1. Why do we set `content` if it's blank?
2. Why the `position` is changed to `absolute` in `:after` and `:before`?
3. Main question is: how are we drawing the arrow on the left side?

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 580px;
  min-height: 65px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 59px;
}

.bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  border-color: transparent #fff;
}

.bubble:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  left: -16px;
  top: 50%;
  border-color: transparent red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="bubble">
    <div class="Pointer">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pseudo-elements are created to **style additional content**. This *content* is what you put in the `content` property. if you don't specify a value for the `content` property it falls to its default value which is `none` . If the content is `none` then there is nothing to style and whatever styling you apply will not have anything to be applied to.

Comment: The arrow is created with two triangles made with the border properties. A red triangle using :before and a white one using :after. The white one is put on top with z-index and the red triangle is put one pixel more to the left. Now it looks like a line is drawn, but it's just showing a small part of the red triangle.

Answer (score 2):

1) The reason you set content as blank is to tell the HTML that you still want the element to show up. If you dont set the content to a blank string (i.e. `content: '';`) then the element doesn't show up.

If you remove the `content: '';` line inside your `.bubble:after` you'll get the following snippet. Which then makes that red arrow filled in.

2) You want the element to be an absolute position to the parent element. So it will always be in the exact location you want it to be.

3) You are drawing the arrow using the `.bubble:before` selector, and the `border-color` property. If you remove transparent from the border-color property inside your .bubble:before selector you get a square. not the nice looking triangle.

Overall, since you're learning CSS, and I'm assuming you're following tutorials, I would suggest if you dont know how something works either comment ONE line out at a time, and then refresh your page. See if any visible changes are on the screen.

To answer this question I got rid of a single line and then refreshed to see how your code was written. Then put it back if i didn't like the changes. :D

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative; 
  width: 580px;
  min-height: 65px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 59px;
}

.bubble:after {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0; 
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top:-15px;
  left: -15px;
  top:50%;
  border-color: transparent #fff;
}

.bubble:before {
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-top:-15px;
  left:-16px;
  top: 50%;
  border-color: transparent red;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bubble">
            <div class="Pointer">
             <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
                industry. 
             </p>
            </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The empty content is simply a way to create a styled "object" that doesn't really contain any "content". The position is referring to the position of the "styled but empty thing" before and after your "bubble", it does not refer to the position of the bubble itself.

Answer (score 0):

For the question "how are we drawing the arrow on left side":
The triangle shape is achieved by the `css` pseudo class `.bubble:after` wherein we have border width given as `15px 15px 15px 0px` for the border width top, right, bottom and left styles. For more such `css` tricks please refer [here](http://www.htmldog.com/references/css/properties/border-width/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Because it is the way the css works :P
2. Absolute is used to To better control position (however it is relative to parent)
3. Here trick is used - arrow on left side is created by red and white triangles (white is on red, but overlap it in this way that 1px boundary of red is visible). Triangles are draw using thick borders of `div` elements - it is better visible on below example:

Look here: https://jsfiddle.net/q30Lnbfr/

```
 .test1 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0;
    width: 0;
    border-color: transparent red;
}

 .test2 {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    width: 30px;
    border-color: green red;
}

<div class="test1">

</div>
<br>
 <div class="test2">

</div>
```

Comment: *Because it is the way the css works* is not really an answer.